# Button background shown on iOS 5/5.1 instead of my background?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, xib

So in my app I am creating, when it is run in the simulator I see the white background images, instead of my transparent background I set. This is with an XIB and not a Storyboard for what it matters.

Examples:
iOS 5.1 and below:
[image: iOS <5.1]

iOS 6 and above:
[image: iOS 6]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem by instead of using a transparent background png, setting the button type to custom, not rounded-rect. This fixed the problem with white backgrounds being shown.

Comment: Very helpful! I ran into the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: but why would this help?